# How to update entity framework database first without loosing validations on entity attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and entity framework database first approach for data. initially I have few entities and I applied validations over the properties. When i update the entities all the validations over the entities disappears.

I got nice article [here](http://jnye.co/Posts/19/adding-validation-to-models-created-by-entity-framework-database-first-c) but does not provide full explanation. Could anybody share live scenarios of how to handle such cases.

Comment: using code first and Migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate partial class for POCO entity, keep the namespace name same as entity framework class file. Now when you update edmx file then those files will not be updated.

This links may help you about validation using metadata
http://www.elevenwinds.com/data-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-database-first